# Pandas- How to create a column filled with empty lists OR store a list in a column

Tags: python, pandas

Newish to coding and even newer to iPython and Pandas. I'm working in Pandas to parse strings in a .csv file so I isolate certain key words and store them as an array in a new column. I've put together the parser, but I'm having trouble finding a way to store the keywords (once they've been isolated from the original .csv) in a new array. I've tried both df.replace and df.insert both nether has gotten me the desired result yet. If there's a way to make the isolated keywords into an iterable data type would be great.
Any suggestions?

```
#abstract from .csv
from pandas import pd

for i in fam['Abstract']:
        abstract = i
        kwords = ['Smith', 'name', 'Brian']

        import string
        from collections import Counter

#changes abstract into dictionary of word counts
        abstract_no_pnct = abstract.translate(None, string.punctuation)
        abstract_as_list = abstract_no_pnct.split()
        abstract_as_cntobj = Counter(abstract_as_list)
        abstract_as_dict = dict(abstract_as_cntobj)

#prints word counts of keywords
        pres_list = []
        for kword in kwords:
        if kword in abstract_as_dict:
                pres_list.append(kword)
                continue

#either append pres_list entries to corresponding list OR 
#save pres_list to corresponding
```

Comment: Firtly, put all your import statements at the top, you don't need to iteratively import them. I use lists in DataFrames all the time. Just do DF.loc[row, col] = '[your, list]'

Comment: I would reconsider how you are storing the data. Putting lists as elements in a dataframe is generally not recommended (not optimized, some things (such as assignement) won't always work as expected)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I used a combination of the two responses to change the original text into a list, saved matches to a list, then joined the list and saved it to a new variable using the format @WoodyPride stated. Now to format, scale, and apply to the actual data set. It's significantly less verbose as well.